# Jest react expect.stringcontaining fails in combination with tohavevalue

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I tried to use *expect.stringcontaining* in a jest test script with create-react-app to do a parial match on a string, but it doesn't work. If I use it with toStrictEqual it works. Is this a bug?

test:

```
test("should update text when typing", () => {
    render(<EditorWindow />);
    userEvent.type(screen.getByRole("textbox"), "bar");
    expect(screen.getByRole("textbox")).toHaveValue(
      expect.stringContaining("bar")
    );
  });

  test("should match text", () => {
    const a = "#title<br>type text here..bar";
    expect(a).toStrictEqual(expect.stringContaining("bar"));
  });
```

result:

```
  <EditorWindow> />
   
    × should update text when typing (46 ms)
    √ should match text

  ● <EditorWindow> /> › should update text when typing

    expect(element).toHaveValue(StringContaining)

    Expected the element to have value:
      StringContaining "bar"
    Received:
      #title<br>type text here..bar

      15 |     render(<EditorWindow />);
      16 |     userEvent.type(screen.getByRole("textbox"), "bar");
    > 17 |     expect(screen.getByRole("textbox")).toHaveValue(
         |                                         ^
      18 |       expect.stringContaining("bar")
      19 |     );
      20 |   });

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/EditorWindow.test.tsx:17:41)
```

I'm using the following libraries:

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.25",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
...
```

Hope someone can help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will work for you? `expect(a.includes('bar')).toBe(true)`

Comment: Thanks, I got the test working with this code:

test("should update text when typing", () => {
    render(<EditorWindow />);
    userEvent.type(screen.getByRole("textbox"), "bar");
    const myTextAreaVal = screen.getByRole("textbox").value;
    expect(myTextAreaVal.includes("bar")).toBe(true);
  }); 
It works, but I get a typescript warning when compiling:

Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.ts(2339) on the code: screen.getByRole("textbox").value;

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get working code without typescript warnings like this:

```
 test("should update text when typing", () => {
    render(<EditorWindow />);
    userEvent.type(screen.getByRole("textbox"), "bar");
    const myTextAreaVal = (screen.getByRole("textbox") as HTMLInputElement)
      .value;
    expect(myTextAreaVal.includes("bar")).toBe(true);
  });
```

I had to use typecasting `as HTMLInputElement` in order to get rid of typescript warnings and to be able to store the value of the text area in a variable `myTextAreaVal`. Then I used `myTestAreaVal.includes` to do a partial match on the string.

Thank you Adrisolid for that tip!